# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed

Tags: docker

My Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

# Install Apache
RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install httpd httpd-tools

# Install EPEL Repo
RUN yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm

# Install PHP
RUN yum install yum-utils
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php73

RUN yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo

# Update Apache Configuration
RUN sed -E -i -e '/<Directory "\/var\/www\/html">/,/<\/Directory>/s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
RUN sed -E -i -e 's/DirectoryIndex (.*)$/DirectoryIndex index.php \1/g' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

EXPOSE 80

# Start Apache
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

When I want to build this image I get

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm]: runc did not terminate successfully
```

How can build a docker image with centos apache and PHP 73?

Comment: Try increasing the RAM for docker and also increase the no of CPU's

Answer (score 0):

remove the three lines

```
# Install EPEL Repo
RUN yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
RUN yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```

those commands don't exist, I suspect you tried to copy instruction for `dnf` and replaced `dnf` with `yum`, that won't work.
And anyways you don't need those.

If you do need them, you can try

```
wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
wget https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-7.rpm epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

or maybe

```
RUN yum -y update; \
    yum install -y epel-release; \
    rpm -Uvh http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
```